# Flutter OverlayEntry not taking width, height

Tags: flutter, dart, size, overlay

I am trying to display an `OverlayEntry` below one of my `Textfields`.

It is working so far, the only problem is with the `OverlayEntry` itself, for some reason, whatever `width` and `height` I give to the child, the Overlay takes all available screen width, and all the way down to the bottom of the screen in height.

Here some code, where as a sample, im just trying to show a small red square of 100x100...not working:

```
OverlayEntry _getOverlay() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => CompositedTransformFollower(
        link: _layerLink,
        showWhenUnlinked: false,
        offset: Offset(0, fieldHeight + 5),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How do I manage the width and height of the OverlayEntry??

Comment: use Positioned.

Comment: please extend a bit in your comment.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

not checked, but might be worked.

use Positioned inside OverlayEntry. check below example.

```
return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child:CompositedTransformFollower(
             link: this._layerLink,
             child: Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
             ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: the CompositedTransformFollower widget is taking care of the positioning since it is linked to the Textfield so im not sure why i need top and left properties in the Positioned, my only concern here is the size properties

Comment: follower tends to extend infinitely if not bounded.

Comment: I tested your solution and seems like its working, the Positioned seems to make the trick, thanks!